# Conditionally disable/enable strict mode in Javascript

Tags: javascript, safari

I need to disable "use strict" in safari due to readonly issues similar to here:

https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/issues/212

I don't want to disable it for every browser though, and it seems that basic conditionals don't work with "use strict".

For example, this doesn't work as expected in Chrome 35:

```
if (true) "use strict";
function isStrict() { console.log(!this); }; 
isStrict(); //false
```

This will work:

```
"use strict";
function isStrict() { console.log(!this); }; 
isStrict(); //true
```

However, ideally I would like to know why Safari is breaking in the first place...but it is seemingly random when it will throw a readonly error. Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Kind of figured...

Any idea what the best approach would be then?

Comment: If it's [this bug](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues/392#issuecomment-7415290), just don't do that.